# How to write media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I am adding these media queries inside the `<head>` of my page:

```
<style type="text/css">

    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        @import url('assets/css/style-smartphones.css');
    }

    /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
        @import url('assets/css/style-tablet.css');
    }

    /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1224px) {
        @import url('assets/css/style-desktop.css')
    }

</style>
```

But the stylesheets files are not loaded.
I double checked the paths and they are correct...
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by myself in this way:

```
    @import url('assets/css/style-smartphones.css') only screen 
            and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px);
    @import url('assets/css/style-tablet.css') only screen 
            and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px);
    @import url('assets/css/style-desktop.css') only screen 
            and (min-width : 1224px);
```